# React Native installRelease Task 'installRelease' not found in root project 'timeReportTool'. Some candidates are: 'uninstallRelease'

Tags: android, react-native

Okay so I am trying to get my react-native into an apk file and install it on a device the assembleRelease works fine but it seems like it doesn't get the signing since I can only install the debug version and not installRelease which gives me the error

Task 'installRelease' not found in root project 'timeReportTool'. Some candidates are: 'uninstallRelease'.

here is the Android block from my build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.timereporttool"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release // add this line as well
    }
}...
```

I do get an app-release-unsigned.apk so it is clearly not getting signed in Android studios it can't sync the gradle because of this line that were there from the start

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
```

in Android Studio the node modules map is empty but it exists in the directory

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to create a signing key and reference it in your project, as described here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android

It's crazy that no one answered this for over a year. There's no way around this issue if you publish a React-Native app to the Play Store.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24446377)

Comment: It's the official documentation, there's no version number or anything else temporary in the URL, and it's way longer than a typical Stack Overflow answer. If they take it down, presumably that means that either Facebook, Github, or the React-Native project are dead, which seems fairly unlikely.

Comment: That doesn't justify putting link-only answers. The URL could change or the page could be moved somewhere else.

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer, if you feel like duplicating the entire contents of the off-site documentation. I don't. This question didn't have an answer at all (FOR OVER A YEAR) until I posted this, and it's an important question.

Answer (score 1):

this is an issue come with i run the command `npx react-native run-android --variant="release"` because I comment this line

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
           // signingConfig signingConfigs.debug <-- this. line
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
           
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
```

after uncomment this line it worked fine.

I always use android studio for release so that's why this issue didn't come for play store.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to unsigned code. You have to follow some sort of steps mentioned in the react native official website for generating a signed apk. Otherwise, even though the apk is created, the user not able to install it on their device.

Refer the following link for generating signed apk.

[Publishing to Google Play Store](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android)